# How to transform response on failed fetch

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux-toolkit, rtk-query

I am using Redux-Toolkit (RTK) Query with React.

My API provides the following responses:

Status 200 OK

```
{
  data: { blah... },
  success: true,
  message: "Data fetched."
}
```

Status 500 Internal Server Error

```
{
  data: null,
  success: false,
  message: "Error: blah"
}
```

I can get RTK Query `transformResponse` to work fine on 200 OK responses.
It will grab the `data`, `success` and `message` parameters and pass them into the custom hook.

**My Problem:** When the API gives a 500 (or non 200 OK) response the `transformResponse` is not run. I can get the `success` and `message` parameters by using `{error.data.message}` and `{error.data.success}` but is there a way to do a `transformResponse` on a failed query so I can just use `{message}`?

My apiSlice.js:

```js
import { MyApiUrl } from './Constants';

export const apiSlice = createApi({
    reducerPath: 'api',
    baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({ baseUrl: MyApiUrl }),
    tagTypes: ['Stuff'],
    endpoints: (builder) => ({
        getStuff: builder.query({
            query: ({ name, category }) => `/Stuff/FindStuff?name=${name}&category=${category}`,
            transformResponse: (res) => { 
                const { data, success, message } = res;
                return res; 
            },
            providesTags: ['Stuff']
        }),
    })
});

export const {
    useGetStuffQuery
} = apiSlice;
```

In the component I use the query hook to get the data:

```js
const { 
    data: stuff,
    isLoading,
    isSuccess,
    isError,
    error,
    success,
    message
} = useGetStuffQuery({ name, category });
```

**Problem 2:** Also, as my API is providing `data` in its response there seems to be a conflict with RTK query using `data` to cover the whole response. All my component queries are `{stuff.data.whatever}` or `{data.data.whatever}`. I can't seem to get the `data` variable from my `transformResponse` into the component as RTK is also using the data variable to cover the whole response.

Answer (score 1):

You can transform error responses as well.

[transformErrorResponse](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/api/createApi#transformerrorresponse)

> A function to manipulate the data returned by a failed query or
> mutation.

To address the second part, instead of returning a response value with a `data` property you can spread it into the transformed response.

```js
export const apiSlice = createApi({
  reducerPath: 'api',
  baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({ baseUrl: MyApiUrl }),
  tagTypes: ['Stuff'],
  endpoints: (builder) => ({
    getStuff: builder.query({
      query: ({ name, category }) =>
         `/Stuff/FindStuff?name=${name}&category=${category}`,
      transformResponse: ({ data, ...response }) => {
        return { ...response, ...data }; 
      },
      transformErrorResponse: ({ data, ...response }) => { 
        return { ...response, ...data }; 
      },
      providesTags: ['Stuff'],
    }),
  })
});
```

Comment: Fantastic! I'll give ti a try :)

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't get it to work. I ended up just using the RTK object error.data.message and error.data.success .

Comment: @ScottishSmile Ah, that's a bummer. I certainly thought that spreading `res.data` into a returned response object `{ data, meta }` or spreading `error.data` into a returned error response object `{error, meta }` would have worked so you wouldn't need `data.data.X` or `error.data.X`.